# How to print rdd in python in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two files on HDFS and I just want to join these two files on a column say employee id.

I am trying to simply print the files to make sure we are reading that correctly from HDFS.

```
lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://ip:8020/emp.txt")
print lines.count()
```

I have tried foreach and println functions as well and I am not able to display file data. 
I am working in python and totally new to both python and spark as well.

Answer (score 18):

This is really easy just do a [collect](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=collect#pyspark.RDD.collect)
**You must be sure that all the data fits the memory on your master**

```
my_rdd = sc.parallelize(xrange(10000000))
print my_rdd.collect()
```

If that is not the case You must just take a sample by using [take](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=take#pyspark.RDD.take) method.

```
# I use an exagerated number to remind you it is very large and won't fit the memory in your master so collect wouldn't work
my_rdd = sc.parallelize(xrange(100000000000000000))
print my_rdd.take(100)
```

Another example using .ipynb:

[image]